# Database Connection Timeout Issue

Tags: python, mysql, sql, query-optimization, database-performance

I have a python code that takes a set of inputs ( possibly 250 ) and then looks up the values corresponding to that input in 2 databases.

```
engine = create_engine(database_url1)
result = {}

for input in input_list:
    sql_query = f"""SELECT *  FROM table 1where name = input limit 1;"""
    db_results = engine.execute(sql_query).fetchall()

    if len(db_results) <= 0:
        sql_query = f"""SELECT *  FROM table 2 where name = input limit 1;"""
        db_results = engine.execute(sql_query).fetchall()

    if len(db_results) <= 0:
        sql_query = f"""SELECT *  FROM table 3 where name = input limit 1;"""
        db_results = engine.execute(sql_query).fetchall()

    if len(db_results) <= 0:
        engine_database2 = create_engine(database_url2)
        sql_query = f"""SELECT *  FROM table 4 where name = input limit 1;"""
        db_results = engine_database2.execute(sql_query).fetchall()
```

I end up getting timeout issue, for large set of inputs.
What is the best way/practice to approach this, so that I am not opening and closing multiple database connections and the performance is better with large set of inputs.

Should i handle the inputs in batches ? will it increase the performance.

Comment: Well, move `engine_database2 = create_engine(database_url2)` out of the loop..?

Comment: What's the specific timeout error? MySQL has a couple of different timeouts, and which one you're hitting depends on how it's configured.

Comment: Function 'xFunction' timed out after 29 seconds and I see that it is not able to establish the connection with large inputs. If i reduce the number of inputs, it works fine.